# CFileDialog crashes on new folder click

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

hello all I'm maintaining this code in MFC

```
 char szFilters[]= "Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt|Register File Definition Files(*.rgf)|*.rgf|All Files(*.*)|*.*|";

CString fileName;
pEdit->GetWindowText(fileName);

CFileDialog fileDlg (TRUE, "txt", fileName,
    OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_NOCHANGEDIR, szFilters, this);

// Display the file dialog. When user clicks OK, fileDlg.DoModal() 
// returns IDOK.
if(IDOK == fileDlg.DoModal())
{
    fileName = fileDlg.GetPathName();
    pEdit->SetWindowText(fileName);
}
```

this is the Visual Studio message:
*This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in APP.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while APP.exe has focus.
The output window may have more diagnostic information.
HEAP[APP.exe]: Heap block at 00000000077C5DA0 modified at 00000000077C5DB4 past requested size of 4
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in APP.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in APP.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while APP.exe has focus.
The output window may have more diagnostic information*

When I clicked the new folder I get a exception saying my app.exe has triggered a break point. and the app crashes. I have tried using different flags from OFN_EXPLORER and such else, but with no luck.

MSDN dosn't give a lot of info about the flags. can you help?

Comment: Your heap is probably corrupted. Are you mixing dlls from different compilers or mixing configurations like using a Debug dll in a release application or using a release dll in a debug application?

Comment: no it's all Debug x64

Comment: By your edit, your heap is definitely corrupted. This is most likely a problem in your code that is not related to the CFileDialog itself. Using the CFileDialog triggers the problem by allocating memory after the heap was corrupted. I would look at allocations and deallocations that happen just before the dialog opens.

Comment: First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCF6940D (KernelBase.dll) in ATE.exe: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but have you terminated `szFilters` correctly?

Comment: Unrelated to your error, but you cannot use `OFN_NOCHANGEDIR` with a FileOpen dialog. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839.aspx) states: *This flag is ineffective for GetOpenFileName.* You should also state the OS version you are using. The common dialogs have changed a lot throughout different versions, and not all changes are transparent to the client.

Comment: SzFilters must be terminated with double pipe ||

Comment: @cha is correct, you need two pipes `||` and that will definitely cause a problem otherwise.

Comment: Give us the version of Windows and Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 update 1, windows 7 x64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented above, you need to change the filters to be correctly terminated (note the "||" at the end):

```
char szFilters[]= "Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt|Register File Definition Files(*.rgf)|*.rgf|All Files(*.*)|*.*||";
```

Not doing so will definitely cause a problem as the filter string will be parsed beyond its end.

Comment: Well I guess this fixed another bug. however I still get the crash when I try to open a new folder.

Comment: @Androidy it's possible to get the errors you report when you mix Debug and Release modules - is this just an exe or do you have dlls as part of the mix?

Comment: I have DLLs but they are all in Debug x64.